# Why is this basic PyQt5 program not working?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

This is a pyqt5 program that is suppossed to set the content of one lineedit to the content of the other lineedit. It is not working in that it you can't edit the line edits. Can someone tell me why and how I can fix it?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        firstenter = QLineEdit(self)
        firstenter.move(140,276)
        firstenter.setFixedWidth(240)

        secondenter = QLineEdit(self)
        secondenter.move(420,276)
        secondenter.setFixedWidth(240)

        equalsighn = QLabel(self)
        equalsighn.setText("=")
        equalsighn.move(395,270)

        def conversion():
            try:
                a = firstenter.displayText()
                b = secondenter.displayText()
                if firstenter.isModified() == True:
                    firstenter.setText(str(b))
                elif secondenter.isModified() == True:
                    secondenter.setText(str(a))

            except:
                if firstenter.isModified() == True:
                    secondenter.setText("")
                if secondenter.isModified() == True:
                    firstenter.setText("")

        firstenter.textEdited.connect(conversion)
        secondenter.textEdited.connect(conversion)

        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')    
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the logic in the first `if` statement is wrong:

```
if firstenter.isModified() == True:
    firstenter.setText(str(b))
```

You're resetting the contents of the first line edit to the second, but since the `secondenter` text is empty to begin with, it sets the `firstenter` text accordingly, thus resetting its contents no matter what you type. Because of that, the second if won't work for the same reason.

The solution is much simpler, and uses [`sender()`] to know which object emitted the signal:

```
    def conversion():
        if self.sender() == firstenter:
            secondenter.setText(firstenter.text())
        else:
            firstenter.setText(secondenter.text())
```

Note that you should use [`text()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) and not `displayText()`, since the latter might return a different result if the [`echoMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#echoMode-prop) is not set to `Normal` (the default).

Also, the `try/exception` is useless, and you shouldn't check against `isModified`, since `textEdited` is always and only emitted when the user changes the text, and not when the text is changed programmatically using `setText()`.

<sub>A suggestion: avoid fixed sizes and positions, using them will probably result in an unusable interface on systems different from yours (because of various reasons, including screen size, DPI and default fonts). You should prefer [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead.</sub>